# DVWA setup PHP function allow_url_include: Disabled

Tags: php, mysql, windows, apache, xampp

I'm setting up DVWA on Windows via XAMPP, and I've searched in Google for about 24 hours - I cannot seem to find the answer.

My problem is setting up the server:

```
PHP function `allow_url_include: Disabled`
```

My config file says it's enabled. Could it have something to do with my ports? Should I set up my server for outside access to my router, or is the internal IP access enough?

When setting up my server I get this:

> **Database Setup**
>
> Click on the 'Create / Reset Database' button below to create or reset your database.
>
> If you get an error make sure you have the correct user credentials in: C:\XAMPP\htdocs\dvwa/config/config.inc.php
>
> Setup Check
>   Operating system: Windows
>   Backend database: MySQL
>   PHP version: 5.5.30
>
> Web Server SERVER_NAME: 192.168.0.13
>
> PHP function display_errors: Enabled (Easy Mode!)
>   PHP function safe_mode: Disabled
>   PHP function allow_url_include: Disabled
>   PHP function allow_url_fopen: Enabled
>   PHP function magic_quotes_gpc: Disabled
>   PHP module php-gd: Installed
>
> reCAPTCHA key: Missing
>
> Writable folder C:\XAMPP\htdocs\dvwa/hackable/uploads/: Yes)
>   Writable file C:\XAMPP\htdocs\dvwa/external/phpids/0.6/lib/IDS/tmp/phpids_log.txt: Yes
>
> Status in red, indicate there will be an issue when trying to complete some modules.

Comment: Okay, so apparently i did something. And now i'm able to get into my DVWA home. However the php-function-allow-url is still disabled. Will this effect DVWA, not being enabled? The server said before that it wouldn't work, but now its kinda working anyway.

Answer (score 8):

To solve the issue, go to:

```
C:\xampp\php\php.ini
```

And change:

```
allow_url_include=Off
```

To:

```
allow_url_include=On
```

Then go to:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\DVWA\config\config.inc.php
```

And change:

```
$_DVWA[ 'recaptcha_public_key' ]  = ' ';
$_DVWA[ 'recaptcha_private_key' ] = ' ';
```

Into:

```
$_DVWA[ 'recaptcha_public_key' ]  = '6LdK7xITAAzzAAJQTfL7fu6I-0aPl8KHHieAT_yJg';
$_DVWA[ 'recaptcha_private_key' ] = '6LdK7xITAzzAAL_uw9YXVUOPoIHPZLfw2K1n5NVQ';
```

Answer (score 4):

I know this is two weeks old at this point but to fix this you will want to modify php.ini, at least on Linux.  I haven't ran into this on Windows, but here is the line you need to change:

```
; Whether to allow include/require to open URLs (like http:// or ftp://) as files.
; http://php.net/allow-url-include
allow_url_include=Off
```

Change that last line to:

```
allow_url_include=on
```

Now, restart the Apache server and reload the URL.

Comment: It works but I should say you must restart apache service on xampp to see the affects .

Answer (score 3):

Found it for Windows and XAMPP installation. Don't bother to change values in `php.ini` file located in `DVWA` Folder. Instead, look for `php.ini` located in XAMPP installation directory e.g. `C:\xampp\php\php.ini`

Search for the string:

```
allow_url_include=
```

Change the value to `allow_url_include=On` and restart `apache`.

Answer (score 3):

For Kali Linux editing "apache2 wide" `php.ini` worked for me:

```
# updatedb
# locate php.ini
/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
/etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
/usr/lib/php/7.2/php.ini-development
/usr/lib/php/7.2/php.ini-production
/usr/lib/php/7.2/php.ini-production.cli
/var/www/html/DVWA-master/php.ini
# nano /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
```

**CTRL + W**, search for *allow_url_include*, set it `On`

```
# service restart apache2
```

And you should have *allow_url_include* enabled

[image: allow_url_include]

Answer (score 1):

Found the problems mates but this for windows but may apply for you

> you need to apply the changes in the "phpForApache.ini" not the "php.in"

Answer (score 0):

Find the using php version using command:
`php -v`
(Many time more than one version of php is installed)
After that go to directory `/etc/php/7.4/apache2`. Here 7.4 is the php version.
In that directory open file using editor or nano and add

```
allow_url_fopen=On
allow_url_include=On
```

to `php.ini` file.

Then, restart apache2 server using `service apache2 restart`
Then refresh the dvwa page in browser

Answer (score -2):

On ubuntu raise same question and I solve it.Just set

`$_DVWA[ 'db_user' ]     = 'root';
$_DVWA[ 'db_password' ] = '';`

Comment: Not sure how this is related to the `allow_url_include` issue as it is disabling a url.

Comment: This post doesn't answer the question